# Тестирование работы с удалённым сервисом

Tags: java, веб-служба, testng

Как можно протестировать работу с удалённым сервисом, т.е. проверить то, насколько правильно формируются запросы к сервису, и сравнить ответы от сервиса с ожидаемым результатом?

Можно ли протестировать это, не просто бросая запросы через `JMeter/HttpAnalyzer/SoapUI/`и т.д., а с помощью кода (т.е. написать для этого какие-либо тесты, наподобие `JUnit`-тестов)?

Answer (score 3):

Можно конечно, формируйте в тесте запрос, отправляйте и проверяйте результат.

Только эти тесты будут не сильно надежными. Они будут зависеть от работы стороннего сервиса. Сервис может не ответить или отвечать дольше чем надо. Данные на сервисе могут меняться, но их формат оставаться статичным.

В данном случае лучше использовать заглушку чужого сервиса и на правильный запрос с вашей стороны возвращать верный ответ от заглушки, на кривой запрос соответственно возвращать ошибку.

Напишите отдельные тесты на формирование запроса, на отправку запроса, на действия если пришел неверный ответ.